# Word Macro to convert Bullets into simple Text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking a way to convert the Bullets in Word document to simple text. E.g.

I have these kind of Bullets:

```
a)->      Apple
b)->      Orange
c)->      Mangoes
```

I want them to be like this:

```
a)Apple
b)Oranges
c)Mangoes
```

I am using this code but it removes the Bullets entirely:

```
Dim oPara As Paragraph

    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs()
       Set r = oPara.Range
        If r.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers = wdListBullet Then
            r.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate _
            ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery) _
                .ListTemplates(1)
        End If
        Set r = Nothing
     Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText what you're after?

It can also be run on a specific list if you're not doing this globally.

ETA: It seems like ConvertNumbersToText takes a NumberType argument (this isn't documented by the 2010 spec that F1 brings up, but it is valid). Perhaps the default doesn't apply to all the bullets in your document. A combination of the three possibilities might work.

```
ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText(wdNumberParagraph) 'Preset numbers you can add to paragraphs by selecting a template in the Bullets and Numbering dialog box.
ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText(wdNumberListNum) 'Default value for LISTNUM fields.
ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText(wdNumberAllNumbers) 'Default value for all other cases.
```

I tend to use the first one, but your case might be different.

Comment: Yes I used this ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText But it will convert only the first bullet in the ActiveDocument. I want to convert all the bullets present in the ActiveDocument.

Comment: Hmm, that's not how it works for me. I've added a little more detail to my answer, maybe it will help.